# project structure and share var under all module controllers

Tags: yii

I have the following structure:

```
modules/group
modules/group/modules/forum
modules/group/modules/gallery
modules/group/modules/events
```

Is this a correct way of structuring groups? or is better

```
modules/group
modules/group/controllers/ForumController.php
modules/group/controllers/GalleryController.php
modules/group/controllers/EventsController.php
```

And another question. I need group object in all actions controllers under group module and i dont want to write the following code in all controllers

```
$group = Group::model()->findByPk($_GET['idgroup']);
```

The url's like:

```
/group/<idgroup>/forum/<idforum>
/group/<idgroup>/gallery/<idgallery>
```

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: @Demian: I did not know how it worked until a few days. I will accept your answer.

Comment: I'll put one together, but it should only be accepted if it *helps* you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a correct way of structuring
>   groups?

The answer depends on a couple things:

- Are you pulling in forum, gallery and events modules from a 3rd party?
- Do forum, gallery and events contain their own models, views and controllers?
- Do you plan on making forum, gallery and events stand-alone modules that others can use in their Yii applications?

If any of the above, then yes, it would make sense to put them into their own modules. Otherwise, adding them to the `group` module would be preferred.

According to Yii documentation:

> A module is a self-contained software
>   unit that consists of models, views,
>   controllers and other supporting
>   components.

---

In regards to the adding the group object to all controller actions, generally I'll add a base Controller class for my module (something like `/group/components/GroupController.php`) and extend that controller rather than the base one in all of my controllers. `GroupController` should extend Yii's `CController` and contain the group object that you want to have accessible from your module's controllers.

Comment: thanks for reply, its really useful. What about if i have another module with forum, eg. /groups/<idgroup>/forum and /community/forum , ¿do i have to create another module named forum in community module? or is possible reuse a module?

Comment: @aprencai: It's reusable as long as it's *built* to be so :) You could create a single forum module and link it into any one of your other modules.